# How can I fix wrong .cabal file of dependent package in Haskell Stack?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I use Haskell Stack in Windows 10

When I try to install gtk as dependency of my own package, I got following messages.

```
glib-0.13.2.2: configure
glib-0.13.2.2: build
Progress: 1/5
--  While building package glib-0.13.2.2 using:
      C:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6012\glib-0.13.2.2\.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\setup\setup --builddir=.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: C:\Users\junyoung\Documents\HaskellProject\StackProject\Hotepad\.stack-work\logs\glib-0.13.2.2.log

    [1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( SetupWrapper.hs, C:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6012\glib-0.13.2.2\.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\setup\SetupWrapper.o )
    [2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6012\glib-0.13.2.2\Setup.hs, C:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6012\glib-0.13.2.2\.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\setup\Main.o )
    Linking C:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Temp\stack6012\glib-0.13.2.2\.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\setup\setup.exe ...
    [1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist\setup-wrapper\Gtk2HsSetup.o )
    [2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist\setup-wrapper\Main.o )
    Linking dist/setup-wrapper\setup.exe ...
    Configuring glib-0.13.2.2...
    Building glib-0.13.2.2...
    Preprocessing library glib-0.13.2.2...
    .stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_utils.o:StoreValue_hsc_utils.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__debugbreak'
    .stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_make.o:StoreValue_hsc_make.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    linking .stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_make.o failed (exit code 1)
    command was: C:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\mingw\bin\gcc.exe .stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_make.o .stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_utils.o -o .stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_make.exe -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Roaming\stack\snapshots\f21484d8\lib\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.3\utf8-string-1.0.1.1-L8eKHa7Iv9q7FVKUYW6u4b -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Roaming\stack\snapshots\64a043b0\lib\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.3\text-1.2.2.1-HmqVQnZSpjaC156ABqPhne -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\lib\binar_3uXFWMoAGBg0xKP9MHKRwi -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\lib\conta_2C3ZI8RgPO2LBMidXKTvIU -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\lib\bytes_6VWy06pWzJq9evDvK2d4w6 -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\lib\deeps_6vMKxt5sPFR0XsbRWvvq59 -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\lib\array_67iodizgJQIIxYVTp4emlA -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\lib\base_HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM -lwsock32 -luser32 -lshell32 -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\lib\integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\lib\ghcpr_8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3 -LC:\Users\junyoung\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\lib/rts -lm -lwsock32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
```

I found that this messages is because of glib.cabal files bug at glib-0.13.2.2, so when I try to install glib separately, I edit glib.cabal (remove `-D___attribute__(A)=` option on cpp) and install clearly.

However, when I try to install it using stack, `stack install gtk` command always takes Hackage one instead of installed glib package.

For short, therefore, my question is, how can I using separately installed glib? Or, is there any way to modify packages .cabal file while installing it, using options or whatever?

Comment: Have the package `glib` locally at your system and point to it under the `packages` section in `stack.yaml`.

Comment: @Sibi Is there no other elegant way to handle this? At least I think, that approach throw out advantages using package manager and make project losing portability, isn't it?

Comment: @JunyoungClareJang what do you think would be a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2):

Stack lets you use a dependency from a local directory, or a github repo. So feel free to fork the project, do the fixes, maybe even do a PR, and then put this into your stack.yaml under "packages" section:

```
- location:
    git: https://github.com/user/repo
    commit: a1b3559090e9c75ce1d46969085fe4f918b2fa82
```